# how to store the scanned Barcode by Barcode scanner in a string without textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode, barcode-scanner

I got a Barcode scanner and working with c# WinForm and a SQL server Database
when I scan a barcode the value appears in the focused textbox
but that means that user have to focus the textbox first
how can I store the scanned Barcode value in a string so I can search it in the database
And What event Should I use (keypress or keydown or what)
I already searched about 57 pages in stackoverflow but I couldn't make any code work so please help

Comment: Does your barcode scanner operate like a keyboard? Do your barcodes follow a consistent pattern (ie a series of 12 digits)? Does the scanner send specific values before and/or after the barcode data (like a return or tab)?

Comment: On Windows Desktop platforms, setting the [Form's KeyPreview property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to true will give priority to the Form's KeyDown/Up/Press events, regardless of the Control or Focus in the Form.

Comment: operate like a keyboard ? yes>>>>follow a consistent pattern (ie a series of 12 digits)? yes>>>send specific values before and/or after the barcode data? it send (return) after